# how to find the overlapping lines of two very big files

Tags: python-3.x

I have two very big tab-delimited files (> 10G). There are some lines that are present in both files with the same first and second fields. How to find these lines in the two files with overlapping first and second fields?

The first file

A      3      mmm      gcd      1467

A      4      ghd      u7      14io

A      5      230      op      892

A      7      36u      ojk      568

................

................

The second file

A      1      m5t      hf      1456

A      3      vcv      uyn      90p

A      4      nm      io      09y

A      6      78      ml      po

A      8      kl      pli      ,ll

................

................

Then I would like to get the first and second lines in the first file, and the second and third lines in the second file.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. When you say first and second lines in first file, what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the first and second files, I want to get the lines in both files that have the same first and second fields.    For example, the first line (A 3 mmm gcd 1467) in the first file has the same first and second fields with the second line (A 3 vcv uyn 90p) in the second file, then I want to get the two lines.  But the two files are very big (>10 G), I am wondering if there is a quick way in python to do that?

Comment: Are this lines sorted? Is it possible for two different lines in same file to have same first and second fields?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, these two files are sorted, and some lines in one file have some first and second fields